# Should the Area51 proposal and scifi.stackexchange site statistics match?

Tags: support, site-statistics

On [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4451/science-fiction), it says we have 8.1 questions/day.  On scifi.se, it says we have 361 questions (=15.7 questions per day after 23 days).

On Area51, it says we have 354 visits/day.  On scifi.se, it says we have 1759 vistors/day.  Perhaps vistors and visits are different things (perhaps it's uniques/views?), but it seems that visits ought to always be higher in that case.

The other statistics (answers/question, users, percentage answered) do match.

Are these statistics wrong in one place?  If so, which one?  Am I misunderstanding and they are measuring different things?

I wondered if this was just heavy caching on Area51, but the difference hasn't changed for several days at least.

Note that these are important statistics for us: if the scifi.se stats are correct, then we are meeting the "healthy beta" numbers.  If the Area51 stats are correct, then we need to improve views **a lot** and are in danger of having too few questions/day as well.

Answer (score 5):

The stats on Area 51 are averaged over the last 14 days. So over the last 14 days of the beta, you have averaged 8.1 questions/day.

Comment: thanks! What are the scifi.se values? Average over the entire life of the site? That would mean a very large decrease in views since the public beta began (which seems odd).

Comment: @Tony Meyer: I am not entirely certain from where  the Scifi-SE values are derived. But the drop is *not* unusual at all. Every single Stack Exchange site starts off the first few days with very high traffic which drops off precipitously. Every site. In the case of Scifi, the 2nd day peaked at about 4-times the normal daily traffic you are seeing now. That is very normal.

Comment: what I thought was unusual was that the private beta would have higher views than public beta, given that only 59 people had access.  The Area51 count gives 5k visitors in 14 days.  It's hard to see what 'y' would give 5k+(2 day total)=1759*y.  Anyway, the overall point is clear: we are far too low in views, so need to figure out a way to fix that.

Comment: Asking great and **interesting questions** drives more Google traffic. Publicizing (with Twitter, etc) great and interesting questions brings in more views and users, too. Use those social links.